# How to extract phone number from multi-line strings in cells in excel

Tags: excel

Example of cells below. As you can see some cells have more info like emails, and some don't have a number but they're all in the same column.

Cell 1

```
Smith, James W
#129432
123 N. Street Road
 Libertyville, IL, 60048
(810) 955-9721 
claudie.predov@hotmail.com
```

Cell 2

```
Evette T Rudnick
#7928253
1308 Stutler Lane
Tidioute, PA, 16351
```

Cell 3

```
David C Ponce
#1234567
2855 Retreat Avenue
 Frenchboro, ME, 04635
(313) 204-6364
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are the numbers always in the format `(###) ###-####`?

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner Thanks for the formating! I was thinking I could use that but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MID and SEARCH:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("(???) ???-????",A1),14),"")
```

[image]

Comment: @Scott Sir, this works `=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1),14),"")` you dont have to use the whole phone number string in search

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya but you may have a `(` in another place.  I find it better when searching to find the longest format they all share to ensure no false positives.

Comment: I want to extract the emails and names as well.  Should I ask a separate question for them? @Scott-Craner

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir thank you, Sir, when we use like that way it takes whole format as one search option right, this always baffled me earlier thank you again for letting me know that, !

Comment: @aalhayekahmc yes one question per post.

Comment: I've posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783341/how-to-extract-email-name-from-multi-line-strings-in-cells-in-excel