# How to extract email & name from multi-line strings in cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example of cells below. As you can see some cells have more info including emails, middle initials or names, but some don't. They're all in the same column.

Cell 1

```
Smith, James
#129432
123 N. Street Road
 Libertyville, IL, 60048
(810) 955-9721 
claudie.predov@hotmail.com
```

Cell 2

```
Evette Tar Rudnick
#7928253
1308 Stutler Lane
Tidioute, PA, 16351
```

Cell 3

```
David Ponce C
#1234567
2855 Retreat Avenue
 Frenchboro, ME, 04635
(313) 204-6364
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try in this way,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **C1**

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[1]")
```

• Formula used in cell **D1**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("@",A1)),FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[last()]"),"")
```

**Note:** I have assumed the strings are segregated within a cell by line breaks hence why `CHAR(10)` has been used.

---

Or, if you have access to the **O365** & currently in **Insider's Beta Channel Version** then you may try using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTSPLIT()` Functions as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **E1**

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,CHAR(10),1)
```

• Formula used in cell **F1**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),6),"")
```

Comment: in `C1`, try `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=1 or contains(.,'@')]"))`

Comment: @JvdV Sir, i forgot, the `contains` option and using of `or` , my bad.

Comment: Also just for fun: `=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),1,6)` would spill result directly.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, this is just **Brilliant** piece of work & I am really astounded, how you crafted this formula.